# How C# projects link the assemblies

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, .net-assembly, assemblies

I'd like to ask a question about the way how C# links its dependencies.

***First case:*** 
I have a C# project that links e.g. **System** assembly. If I add reference from the **Assembly->Framework** window:
[image]

and then double click on the System assembly on the reference view: 
[image]

the path to the assembly would be: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll**

But if I have .nuget enabled and it has downloaded the assemblies, the link to the system assembly would be magically changed to the: **C:\Users\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.dll**

Why I say "magically" is because I can't see the place that explicitly says - from now take the assembly from that direction.

***Second case:*** 
When I have .nuget assemblies downloaded, on the Project Reference Window I see next thing:

[image]

Two assemblies of the different versions are linked to my project, one is from the place where .nuget resides, the other is from the place where the .NET Framework resides. Question: which one will be taken into account? Both?

Just a thought, though.

When I work with C++ project, everything is super clear and straightforward, I may have few different SDKs installed, but when I define the SDK version and the toolset to be use and - the project will take assemblies from the defined place. It doesn't try to load something from different place, unless I specified so.

Maybe C# projects have similar configuration abilities but I'm not aware of them. 
Could somebody help me with understanding that?

**Update**

Just realized that my statement here: *When I have .nuget assemblies downloaded, on the Project Reference Window I see next thing:* might be confucing. Adding full screen shot where I have listed to different assemblies versions:
[image]

Also, adding my project file screenshot, to show that it doesn't have a place where it explicitly says to where from to take the assembly:
[image]

Comment: When you are downloading something from nuget, it will change your project file, and can change references (which stored in your project file, *.csproj) too. If you edit your *.csproj file, you can find all your project's references there.

Comment: @SeM could you please tell what exactly will be changed on the project file? Since the place where is defined the linked assemblies remains unchanged. e.g.: 
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
</ItemGroup>
it is the same independently of .nuget presence

Comment: which assemblies  you are downloading from nuget? Please tell your exact actions, so we would be able to recreate your problem.

Comment: @SeM it downloads **Microsoft.NETCore** and all related dependencies.
I have two projects: one is UWP (an EDGE Extension) and the second is C# (a.k.a DesktopBridge app)

Comment: I think it's worth to point out that you picked a very particular example of a referenced assembly since NETCore is targeting a specific version of the .NET framework which is really one step beyond the usual linking dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Filburt. Yes, it appears that NetCore adds additional dependency.

Comment: @Andriy Sure it will add, it's different framework, also if you are creating extension for edge, why are you using .net core?

Comment: Could you please help me with that? 
I can add assemblies by specifying the direct location, but then everybody else who will be working with my project\solution later (CI especially) will need to have SDK installed on the same place where it is installed on my pc. On the C# project there are no much macrosses in compare with C++.

Comment: @Andriy That's why it's preferable to do it via nuget (for SDK and extensions) - it will handle reference paths relative to your project/solution and re-create everything for everyone working on the project/solution. Just make sure you only check in package configuration, not the package contents and you're good.

Comment: @Andriy Also try to not compare these two languages together, c# is a whole another thing, you should consider it in that way, to learn something new. Its advantages/disadvantages compare to c++ is just a point of view thing and comes from task's requirements. For example Garbage Collection in c# and flexible memory management in c++.

Comment: Not all references has a `HintPath` none of your duplicated assemblies are in the csproj snippet you've added so that doesn't really clarify the situation. If you want help with this show the XML for the assemblies your asking about.

Comment: I do think if your just starting out in C# this is very in depth. Why don't you just delete the duplicated assemblies and move on? It feels like you've gotten a bit caught trying to understand the (complicated) why when the solution is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

This question is all a bit muddled. An important distinction you need to think about is how **visual studio references assemblies** and how your **compiled application** will.

### Visual Studio

When you add a reference in visual studio it adds a record into the csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The above includes a "hint path". This tells visual studio where it thinks the assembly resides. When you compile your app VS will check this path for the assembly.

when you install an assembly using Nuget. Nuget adds the assembly into `packages` folder and add's a reference to this assembly into you csproj file. with a hint path that points at this location. So VS will load the assembly this location.

### Compilation

When you compile your app the result of this is a runnable application (dll,exe, etc). This runnable application is a machine code translation of your C#. It includes "links" (DLL stands for **D**ynamic **L**ink **L**ibrary) to assemblies.

### `bin` folder

When you compile your app you will have two options on the reference in VS:

[image]

If `copy local` is `True` visual studio will include the dll in the manifest of the build. This basically means that dll will end up in the `bin` folder. If it's false it won't include it and it will be assumed that the application will be able to reference this assembly from somewhere else.

### So where else can it load assemblies from?

Your compiled application will look for assemblies based on a hierachy. The first place it will look for an assembly that matches your manifest is the `bin` folder. As we've already noted though the assemblies aren't always here.

If it can't find it here it will then check the machine it is running on to see if it has access to these assemblies. The next location it checks is a concept called the [**Global Assembly Cache**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). This is a register of assemblies registered on the machine and the assemblies location.

If it still can't find it it, it will throw an exception.

> Two assemblies of the different versions are linked to my projectwhich
>   one will be taken into account? Both?

No it can't use both. As [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287137/how-c-sharp-projects-link-the-assemblies/50288046?noredirect=1#comment87592159_50288046) you can use [`alias`(es) to reference a particular assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) but this still uses one assembly at a time.

If you don't specify an `alias` though, I wouldn't expect this to work? I'd expect VS to complain it doesn't know which one to use. You could have an assembly re-direct configured in your `app.config`/`web.config`:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This will map competing assemblies to one particular version (usually the most recent)

Comment: You can have two assemblies of the same name referenced. That's the point of being able to apply aliases to references.

Comment: > Does you application even compile? - yes, it does. And it actually works.

Comment: Does it have an assembly redirect or alias configured? @Andriy?

Comment: do you use this assembly or is it just referenced? If it's not used the pre-compiler will strip it out of the manifest.